# Method concurrency

Tags: java, function

Let's say I have two methods in a method

```
void hello(){
    method1();
    method2();
}
```

Does method2 start only after complete execution of method1 all the time?

Comment: Yes. This is guaranteed.

Comment: Yes java follows top down decision approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It is guaranteed.  The body of a method is a block, and the [JLS 14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2) states:

> A block is executed by executing each of the local variable declaration statements and other statements in order from first to last (left to right).

Answer (score 2):

yes, that's the definition of the language. If there is no threading involved, one method needs to return before the next one is invoked.